# Vaadin 8 - Grid validator to "hear" values across cells

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I have the columns `Minimum` and `Maximum` in Vaadin 8 `Grid`. 
These columns are editable. I need to make validators also check these 2 values against one another 
so that if the value entered in field `Maximum` is less than the value of `Minimum` entry in that row, 
the validator will issue an error and vice versa.

the code is as follows:

```
grid.addColumn(AuditParams::getMaxAmt, new NumberRenderer())
.setId("max")
.setCaption("Max")
.setEditorBinding(grid
        .getEditor()
        .getBinder()
        .forField(new TextField())
        .withConverter(new StringToFloatConverter("Enter a value greater than 0"))
           .withValidator(v -> v>0.0f, "Must be a positive value")
           .withValidator(v -> v<Constants.MAX_AMT, "Maximum can be "+Constants.MAX_AMT)
        .bind(AuditParams::getMaxAmt, AuditParams::setMaxAmt)
);
```

How can this be done in Vaadin 8? How to pass the value of another cell to the validator?

TIA

//--------------------

I tried adding the following validator to the "max" column after the other two validators:

```
           .withValidator(v -> v>=((Float)grid.getColumn("min")
               .getEditorBinding().getField().getValue()), 
               "Incorrect range")
```

This validator is never passing anything - always issues the error "Incorrect range".

//--------------------

more accurately - tried the following validator and it works.

```
           .withValidator(v -> v>=(Float.parseFloat((String)(grid.getColumn("min")
               .getEditorBinding().getField().getValue()))), 
               "Incorrect range")
```

however - the numbers are displayed with formatting (`,` between every 3 digits) and validator is attempting to read it as a number - without the format. This still throwing the error unless i get rid of those comma-s while editing. Will ask this in another Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second edit in the question solved it. I got around the number format issue by explicitly converting the `String` back from the formatted form before passing to `parseFloat()`. Works fully to the effect.

Answer (score 0):

With field level validation you can only can as far as single field. Bean level validation can be used when you have more than single field to check. Please note that you might encounter some issues here, and might need some workarounds (api has changes since I encountered some limitations, so I don't know current situation) https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10406

Comment: gone further to the other field in field validator - see the explicit call above